# How can I boot Linux Kernel with my own init boot arguments?

Tags: python, linux-kernel

My intentions are actually to run python scripts on the Linux Kernel. I have seen the init boot arguments and what I want that when I boot the Kernel, It automatically starts my python script. According to what i have read on the internet, the init argument can allow me to do this. Is this true? And if so, how can i do this?

Comment: You should consider launching via an init script.  See /etc/init/rc.*.

Comment: If you really want to run your python script as the init process, I imagine you would first have to convert it to a standalone executable using something like [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), and then edit the kernel command line in your boot loader to include an option similar to `init=/path/to/my/program`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Can't i also use an inbuilt Python interpreter?

Comment: The program you pass on the `init=` line cannot have any arguments, and I don't think it can be a script using the "shebang" `#!` mechanism, but maybe it can.

Comment: It turns out you may be able to use a "shebang" `#!` script after all according to  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/init.txt